# php won't work for some reason

Tags: php, iframe

Well, I'm trying to get an iframe from a URL of this sort: http://mydomain.com/frame.php?q=http://someotherdomain.com

For some reason I am getting a server error with this code and cannot figure out why. Does anyone see something wrong?

Thanks!

```
<?php

$q = $_GET('q');

function getTitle($Url){
        $str = file_get_contents($Url);
        if(strlen($str)>0){
                preg_match("/\<title\>(.*)\<\/title\>/",$str,$title);
                return $title[1];
        }
};

?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title><?php echo getTitle($q) ?></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>

<body>

<?php echo "<iframe src='".$q."' style='width:100%;height:100%;border:0;'></iframe>" ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, for starters, this

```
$q = $_GET('q');
```

should be

```
$q = $_GET['q'];
```

***PLEASE NOTE***
This method you are using is **highly** insecure.  Consider a malicious person making the following request.

```
http://mydomain.com/frame.php?q=..%2F..%2F..%2F..%2Fetc%2Fapache2%2Fhttpd.conf
```

By providing different values of q, the *attacker* can potentially read any file readable by the webserver's user.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php

$URL = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

/* make sure the title is the first parameter and only param passed, otherwise include a ltrim to get rid of everything starting with & */
$q = rtrim('=', $URL['query']);

?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title><?php=$q?></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>

<body style="margin: 0;">

<?php='<iframe src="' . $whateverURL . '" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; border: 0px;" />'?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

take a look at your apache log error
it is usually at:

```
tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log
```

Comment: Ok, it says Fatal error:  Function name must be a string in /var/www/clients/client0/web10/web/envios/redirect.php on line 3

Comment: can you please copy redirect.php, line 3 on your question?